# Как сделать наложение картинки на другую картинку, как на примере HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Как также сделать палку на фоне свечения? (элементы скачены, не пойму как их расположить
re[image: )]

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность - лучше скачать в объединненом  SVG-файле. Если нет, то я бы сделал пятно как псевдоэлемент слэша через  ":after" или через абсолютное позиционирование - решать вам как удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

было бы что скачивать...)

```css
b{
font-size: 40px;
background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, #80f 1px, black 50px);
padding: 50px;
margin: 25px;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<b>/</b>
```